# How to handle UITableView with different cell height?

Tags: uitableview, delegates, height

each cell in my table has a label, with maximum three lines, so the cell height depends on the label's height, I know the delegate method that returns height for a specific cell(NSIndexPath), but I need to get the actual cell in order to determine the height, and if I call cellForRow:atIndexPath: in heightForCell:, it loops infinitely, I guess cellForRow also calls heightForCell. So is there any way I can handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSStrings size for string in the heightForRow: delegate method e.g.

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(300, 800); //max x width and y height
NSString *cellTitle = @"Lorem ipsum";
UIFont *stringFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]; // use the same font your using on the cell
CGSize cellStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:stringFont constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

This will give you a CGSize you can then use the height from here and add a little padding. You can find more information here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Use `– sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` of `NSString` (you can find more on this on this portal) or use an array containing height for every `indexPath` as shown in this example (SectionInfo class) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html.